# Existing data serialized as hash produces error when upgrading to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently upgrading a Ruby on Rails app from 4.2 to 5.0 and am running into a roadblock concerning fields that store data as a serialized hash. For instance, I have

```
class Club
  serialize :social_media, Hash
end
```

When creating new clubs and inputting the social media everything works fine, but for the existing social media data I'm getting:

> ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a ActionController::Parameters.

How can I convert all of the existing data from `ActionController::Parameter` objects to simple hashes? Database is mysql.

Comment: Which database are you using? I ask mostly because there might be better options that `serialize` and since you're going to be fixing and rewriting all this data anyway, this might be a good time to get rid of `serialize` completely.

Comment: Currently using myql.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize):

> **serialize**(attr_name, class_name_or_coder = Object)
>
> [...] If `class_name` is specified, the serialized object must be of that class on assignment and retrieval. Otherwise `SerializationTypeMismatch` will be raised.

So when you say this:

```
serialize :social_media, Hash
```

ActiveRecord will require the unserialized `social_media` to be a `Hash`. However, as noted by [vnbrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48773916/479863), `ActionController::Parameters` no longer subclasses `Hash` like it used to and you have a table full of serialized `ActionController::Parameters` instances. If you look at the raw YAML data in your `social_media` column, you'll see a bunch of strings like:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters...
```

rather than Hashes like this:

```
---\n:key: value...
```

You should fix up all your existing data to have YAMLized Hashes in `social_media` rather than `ActionController::Parameters` and whatever else is in there. This process will be somewhat unpleasant:

1. Pull each `social_media` out of the table as a string.
2. Unpack that YAML string into a Ruby object: `obj = YAML.load(str)`.
3. Convert that object to a Hash: `h = obj.to_unsafe_h`.
4. Write that Hash back to a YAML string: `str = h.to_yaml`.
5. Put that string back into the database to replace the old one from **(1)**.

Note the [`to_unsafe_h`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_unsafe_h) call in **(3)**. Just calling [`to_h`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h) (or [`to_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_hash) for that matter) on an `ActionController::Parameters` instance will give you an exception in Rails5, you have to include a `permit` call to filter the parameters first:

```
h = params.to_h                   # Exception!
h = params.permit(:whatever).to_h # Indifferent access hash with one entry
```

If you use `to_unsafe_h` (or `to_unsafe_hash`) then you get the whole thing in a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. Of course, if you really want a plain old Hash then you'd say:

```
h = obj.to_unsafe_h.to_h
```

to unwrap the indifferent access wrapper as well. This also assumes that you only have `ActionController::Parameters` in `social_media` so you might need to include an `obj.respond_to?(:to_unsafe_hash)` check to see how you unpack your `social_media` values.

You could do the above data migration through direct database access in a Rails migration. This could be really cumbersome depending on how nice the low level MySQL interface is. Alternatively, you could create a simplified model class in your migration, something sort of like this:

```
class YourMigration < ...
  class ModelHack < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'clubs'
    serialize :social_media
  end

  def up
    ModelHack.all.each do |m|
      # Update this to match your real data and what you want `h` to be.
      h = m.social_media.to_unsafe_h.to_h
      m.social_media = h
      m.save!
    end
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

You'd want to use `find_in_batches` or `in_batches_of` instead `all` if you have a lot of `Club`s of course.

---

If your MySQL supports `json` columns and ActiveRecord works with MySQL's `json` columns (sorry, PostgreSQL guy here), then this might be a good time to change the column to `json` and run far away from `serialize`.

Answer (score 6):

Extending on short's reply - a solution that does not require a database migration:

```
class Serializer
  def self.load(value)
    obj = YAML.load(value || "{}")
    if obj.respond_to?(:to_unsafe_h)
      obj.to_unsafe_h
    else
      obj
    end
  end
  def self.dump(value)
    value = if value.respond_to?(:to_unsafe_h)
      value.to_unsafe_h
    else
      value
    end
    YAML.dump(value)
  end
end

serialize :social_media, Serializer
```

Now `club.social_media` will work whether it was created on Rails 4 or on Rails 5.

Comment: thanks @jpw - I edited my answer to handle the nil case.

Answer (score 2):

The reply by @schor was a life-saver, but I kept getting `no implicit conversion of nil into String` errors when doing the YAML.load(value).

What worked for me was:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  class NewSerializer
    def self.load(value)
      return {} if !value #### THIS NEW LINE
      obj = YAML.load(value)
      if obj.respond_to?(:to_unsafe_h)
        obj.to_unsafe_h
      else
        obj
      end
    end
    def self.dump(value)
      if value.respond_to?(:to_unsafe_h)
        YAML.dump(value.to_unsafe_h)
      else
        YAML.dump(value)
      end
    end
  end

  serialize :some_hash_field, NewSerializer
end
```

I gotta admin the Rails team totally blindsided me on this one, a most unwelcome breaking change that doesn't even let an app fetch the "old" data.

Answer (score 0):

The [official Ruby on Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#actioncontroller-parameters-no-longer-inherits-from-hashwithindifferentaccess) has a section about upgrading between Rails versions that explains more about the error you have:

> **`ActionController::Parameters` No Longer Inherits from `HashWithIndifferentAccess`**
> Calling params in your application will now return an object instead of a hash. If your parameters are already permitted, then you will not need to make any changes. If you are regardless of `permitted?` you will need to upgrade your application to first permit and then convert to a hash.
>
> ```
> params.permit([:proceed_to, :return_to]).to_h
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a bit confused though. I'm not calling `params` but `club.social_media['facebook']` which is what causes the error because `social_media` isn't a hash but and ActionController::Parameter object.

Answer (score 0):

### Run a migration on Rails 4 to prepare the data for Rails 5.

*We're going through the exact same thing, except we serialize as `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` instead of just `Hash`, which I recommend doing, but I'll provide my answer here for just a simple `Hash`.*

If you have not yet upgraded to Rails 5, which I hope you haven't and your tests have uncovered this issue, you can run a migration on the Rails 4 branch that will get your data ready for Rails 5.

It essentially re-serializes all of your records from `ActionController::Parameters` to `Hash` while in Rails 4 and `ActionController::Parameters` still inherits from `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

```rb
class ConvertSerializedActionControllerParametersToHashInClubs < ActiveRecord::Migration

  disable_ddl_transaction! # This prevents the locking of the table (e.g. in production).

  def up
    clubs = Club.where.not( social_media: nil )

    total_records = clubs.count

    say "Updating #{ total_records } records."

    clubs.each.with_index( 1 ) do |club, index|
      say "Updating #{ index } of #{ total_records }...", true
      club.social_media = club.social_media.to_h
      club.social_media_will_change!
      club.save
    end
  end

  def down
    puts "Cannot be reverse! See backup table."
  end

end
```

If you have multiple columns that need to be converted, it's easy to modify this migration to convert all of the necessary tables and columns.

Depending on when you do this, your data should be ready for Rails 5.