# Existing data serialized as Array isn't stored when upgrading to RoR 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have almost upgraded my RoR application from v4 to v5 and there are some more things to be done in order to finish the process.

In my RoR v4 application I was using attributes that was `serialize`d as Hash and Array:

```
class ModelOne < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :attribute_one_names, Hash
end

class ModelTwo < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :attribute_two_names, Array
end
```

Now I need to update records in the database to match the new RoR v5 requirements.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773769/existing-data-serialized-as-hash-produces-error-when-upgrading-to-rails-5#answer-48775771) I can successfully migrate the `attribute_one_names` (Hash) data by running the following migration:

```
class MigrationOneFromRor4ToRor5 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  class ModelOne < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'model_one'
    serialize :attribute_one_names
  end

  def up
    ModelOne.all.each do |m|
      h = m.attribute_one_names.to_unsafe_h.to_h
      m.attribute_one_names = h

      m.save!
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is with the `attribute_two_names` (Array) data.

```
class MigrationTwoFromRor4ToRor5 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  class ModelTwo < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'model_two'
    serialize :attribute_two_names
  end

  def up
    ModelTwo.all.each do |m|
      array_of_names = []
      m.attribute_two_names.each do |name|
        array_of_names << name.to_unsafe_h.to_h
      end

      # Output 1:
      puts array_of_names.inspect 
      # => [{"name"=>"Website1Name", "url"=>"http://www.website1.com"}, {"name"=>"Website2Name", "url"=>"http://www.website2.com"}]
      puts m.attribute_two_names.inspect 
      # => [<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Website1Name", "url"=>"http://www.website1.com"} permitted: false>, <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Website2Name", "url"=>"http://www.website2.com"} permitted: false>]

      m.attribute_two_names = array_of_names

      # Output 2:
      puts m.attribute_two_names.inspect
      # => [{"name"=>"Website1Name", "url"=>"http://www.website1.com"}, {"name"=>"Website2Name", "url"=>"http://www.website2.com"}]

      m.save!

      # Output 3:
      puts m.attribute_two_names.inspect 
      # => []
    end

  end
end
```

In fact, by running this migration, `--- []` values are stored into the database regardless of the existing data serialized as Array. That is, a `--- []` value is stored for each record regardless of the previously data present in the database.

How can I solve the problem?

**Note**:

Before running the MigrationTwoFromRor4ToRor5, in the `attribute_two_names` database column there are values like these:

```
---
- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  name: Website1Name
  url: http://www.website1.com
- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  name: Website2Name
  url: http://www.website2.com

---
- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  name: Website1Name
  url: http://www.website1.com
- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  name: Website2Name
  url: http://www.website2.com
```

Comment: This looks like the same problem as the duplicate but maybe not 100% duplicate. The solution should apply though: manually unpack everything with `YAML.load`, convert things as necessary, `to_yaml` them by hand, and put them back in. All using low level database access. And make sure you're always putting plain arrays and hashes through `serialize` (or better, forget `serialize` exists and use something sane like a JSON column or separate tables). Let me know if I'm way off base the dup-hammer.

Comment: Also, since you seem to have an array of `ActionController::Parameters` and `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` instances, you'll need to unpack the outer array and then convert each element inside the array to a plain old hash. Perhaps something is going wrong in `array_of_names << name.to_unsafe_h.to_h`. Ugh, `serialize` is the devil.

Comment: @muistooshort OK for "This LOOKS LIKE the same problem as the duplicate but maybe not 100% duplicate". Can you provide an example of what you are writing? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Seems that they've changed how the dup-hammer works so I can't re-open this on my own.  Anyway, try replacing your `m.attribute_two_names.each ...` with `array_of_names = m.attribute_two_names.map(&:as_json)` (i.e. use `#as_json` to convert everything to simple arrays and hashes rather than trying to do it with `#to_unsafe_h` and `#to_h`). And why database are you using?

Comment: @muistooshort I tried to use `array_of_names = m.attribute_two_names.map(&:as_json)` as you wrote but I still get the database populated with all `--- []` values.

Comment: @muistooshort I updated the question by adding outputted info during the migration, if this can help.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm using MySQL

Comment: What happens if you drop `serialize :attribute_two_names` from `ModelTwo` and then say `m.attribute_two_names = array_of_names.to_yaml` (i.e. deal with the YAMLization yourself)? Does your version of MySQL support JSON columns? Might be a good time to replace `serialize` with something sane.

Comment: You'd be doing something more like `m.attribute_two_names = YAML.load(m.attribute_two_names).as_json.to_yaml; m.save!` in this case.

Comment: @muistooshort If I run `m.attribute_two_names = array_of_names.to_yaml` then I get the error "751 unexpected token at '--- []".

Comment: Did you remove the `serialize :attribute_two_names` part? I'm suggesting that you treat the column as text in the migration and handle the YAML side of things by hand.

Comment: Ops! Now I get the error "can't serialize `attribute_two_names`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "--- []\n""

Comment: That suggests that it is using the real version of `ModelTwo` from `app/models/model_two.rb` rather than the one you're defining in your migration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try unpacking the YAML by hand to get plain old hashes and arrays then then manually re-YAML-ing that data. Something like this:

```
class MigrationTwoFromRor4ToRor5 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  # Make sure this name is not used by any real models
  # as we want our own completely separate interface to
  # the `model_two` table.
  class ModelTwoForMigrationChicanery < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'model_two'
    # We'll be treating `attribute_two_names` as just
    # a blob of text in here so no `serialize`.
  end

  def up
    ModelTwoForMigrationChicanery.all.each do |m|
      # Unpack the YAML that `serialize` uses.
      a = YAML.load(m.attribute_two_names)

      # Using `as_json` is a convenient way to unwrap 
      # all the `ActionController::Parameters` and
      # `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`
      # noise that go into the database. `#as_json`
      # on both of those give you plain old hashes.
      a = a.as_json

      # Manually YAMLize the cleaned up data.
      m.attribute_two_names = a.to_yaml

      # And put it back in the database.
      m.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Once all this is sorted out, you should get something into your models and controllers to ensure that only plain arrays and hashes get through to `serialize`. I'd also recommend moving away from `serialize` to something sane like JSON column types (if your database supports it and ActiveRecord supports your database's support of it).

Comment: I get the error "no implicit conversion of Array into String" at `YAML.load(m.attribute_two_names)`.

Comment: That happens when you `YAML.load(['some','array'])` so you're probably not using the `ModelTwoForMigrationChicanery` trickery and have a `serialize` slipping in from the main `app/models/` file.